# Space in properties file

Tags: java

I load `Properties` from ini file:

```
input = new FileInputStream("props.ini");
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(input);
```

`props.ini` content:

```
52=0
52 53=0
```

Because of some unknown reason I have only one property in `prop` - `52 53=0`. I found that if key contains several words, only first word is important and if first word exists in properties file it will not be added.

How to fix problem if I need key containing several words?

Comment: replace the space by another character like `.`or `_`

Comment: try to escape empty space: `\ `

Comment: I think as @jhamon wrote, that's often way, how it's done :)

Comment: can I use \ for asci representation in HEX  like \x55  too?